# How to detect the completion of a Tcl coroutine?

Tags: tcl, coroutine

I'd like to find a nice way in Tcl to detect the end of a coroutine. Consider:

```
coroutine cor apply {{} {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
}}

try {
    puts [cor]
    puts [cor]
    puts [cor]
    puts [cor]
} trap {TCL LOOKUP COMMAND cor} {e} {
    puts "done"
}
```

This works, but it feels like a hack and it is brittle. If I rename `cor` and forget to rename it in the trap, it fails. If I leave out the `cor` in the trap, it will catch unrelated typos.

There's got to be a better way. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect if a command still exists, use `info commands` and check the length of list it returns. (I'm assuming you can guarantee that there are no glob characters in the command's name; if that's true, the check is very cheap.)

```
while {[llength [info commands cor]]} {
    puts [cor]
}
```

However, if you are intending the coroutine to work as a generator and only be used in a loop, you can get it to signal that it is done directly. To do that, make it produce a `break`.

```
coroutine cor apply {{} {
    yield [info coroutine];  # A sensible result from [coroutine]
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    return -code break
    # [tailcall break] would also work
}}

while true {
    puts [cor]
}
```

The trick is that you *don't* `yield` the break; you use it as the terminal result of the coroutine. (Your old coroutine was using the result of the `yield` as that, probably principally by luck.)

---

In writing this, I've noticed a bug. That loop to run the coroutine doesn't work at the top level in 8.6.8 (the only version I've checked with). No idea why. It's fine in a procedure/`apply` context (where it is natural to pass the coroutine name as an argument):

```
apply {c {
    while true {
        puts [$c]
    }
}} cor
```

The bytecode for these various ways of running does not appear meaningfully different. Forcing interpretation also makes things work, which is a *great* indication that this is a real bug.

```
set while while
$while true {
    puts [cor]
}
```

Comment: FWIW: `tailcall break` works for the top-level case as expected (8.6.9).