# Get value from loop while processing is not completed

Tags: tcl

This topic may have been (certainly) discussed before, but since I don’t know what it’s called, I ask the question...
My goal is to get the value of the variable during my loop **while** like **[gets ...]** tcl command

```
proc GetValue {var} {

    upvar $var local
    set i 0

    while {$i < 5} {
        set local $i
        incr i
    }
    
    return 0
}

while {[GetValue val] != 0} {
    puts "Line value = $val"
}
```

And I would like this result :

```
Line value = 0
Line value = 1
Line value = 2
Line value = 3
Line value = 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [`coroutine`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/coroutine.htm) to make a [*generator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tcl 8.6

proc GetValue {max} {
    set i 0
    set var [yield [info coroutine]]
    while {$i < $max} {
        upvar $var local
        set local $i
        incr i
        set var [yield $i]
    }
    return 0
}

coroutine looper GetValue 5
while {[looper val] > 0} {
    puts "Line value = $val"
}
```

Running it:

```
$ tclsh example.tcl
Line value = 0
Line value = 1
Line value = 2
Line value = 3
Line value = 4
```

This creates a [coroutine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) named `looper` that, every time it's invoked with a variable name, resumes executing `GetValue`, which sets that variable and `yield`s the current value of the loop counter back to the caller until it's 5, when it returns 0 and ends.

Comment: It's very common to use a unique name for each new coroutine created, and store that in a variable (`set looper [coroutine loop[incr counter] GetValue 5]`) and invoke it (`$looper val`), hence the first `yield` idiomatically returning `[info coroutine]`.

Comment: It's possible to write the code to not need a coroutine… but it does not look like a loop either. Continuation-passing-style programming is not exactly easy on the brain; the language runtime is much better at doing the necessary state management than the programmer is.

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed you could decipher a generator out of that question. Plus nicely coded.

Comment: @Shawn Is it possible not to use a maximum value to use your generator? Finally Is that who’s handling the end of coroutine ?

Comment: @Mkn You can use whatever's appropriate to end the loop; your code counted up to 5 so I did the same, just as an argument instead of a fixed number to make it more flexible.

Comment: @Shawn are you agree with this ? If arg max is omitted, I can write my coroutine like this  `proc GetValue {} {set i 0 ; set var [yield [info coroutine]] ;while {1} {upvar $var local;set local $i;incr i; if {$i == 5} {break};set var [yield $i]}; puts end;return 0}`

Comment: @Mkn Sure (Given the inherit legibility problems from non-trivial bits of code in comments), though I think the original (Or an equivalent `for` loop) is better style.

Comment: @Shawn you are right but I wanted to be sure, sorry for the style and the code in the **comment**

Comment: @Mkn This question might be interesting as another way to end the coroutine and stop looping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273578/how-to-detect-the-completion-of-a-tcl-coroutine